# Get the content of a specific page (by ID)

Tags: pages, content

I have the following front-page template made:

[image]

In place of those large [Lorem Ipsum](http://www.lipsum.com/) blocks, I need to show an "excerpt" from a specific page to fill that box (a certain number of characters).

How do I get a pages content in String format so that I can echo it out and trim down to a certain number of characters?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

```
<?php

// would echo post 7's content up until the <!--more--> tag
$post_7 = get_post(7); 
$excerpt = $post_7->post_excerpt;
echo $excerpt;

// would get post 12's entire content after which you
// can manipulate it with your own trimming preferences
$post_12 = get_post(12); 
$trim_me = $post_12->post_content;
my_trim_function( $trim_me );

?>
```

Comment: based on your code that did not work for me I got this working if it helps anyone - $post_info = get_post( 24 );
   $content = $post_info->post_content;
   echo $content;

Answer (score 24):

Here you go !

```
<?php
$my_id = 5369;
$post_id_5369 = get_post($my_id);
$content = $post_id_5369->post_content;
$content = apply_filters('the_content', $content);
$content = str_replace(']]>', ']]>', $content);
echo $content;
?>
```

Comment: Please, explain what the code does and how it answers the question. Some users may not understand the code without a little explanation.

Comment: I really like the way you added `the_content` filter. +1 for that.

Comment: Works beautiful!

Comment: What does the str_replace do?

Comment: What is `$content = str_replace(']]>', ']]>', $content);` for?

Answer (score 9):

```
$post   = get_post( 42 );

$output =  apply_filters( 'the_content', $post->post_content );

echo $output;
```

from https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post/

Comment: This is the least verbose answer. Love it.

Answer (score 4):

you can use this code it is work fine 
change page_id=19 with your page number:

```
<?php $the_query = new WP_Query( 'page_id=19' ); ?>

<?php while ($the_query -> have_posts()) : $the_query -> the_post();  ?>

                       <?php the_excerpt(); ?>


     <?php endwhile;?>
```

Comment: Wellcome to this site. It seems that thisis your first answer. A explanation of why and how your answer solves the problem is always good.

Answer (score 1):

If you're in the loop do this:

```
<?php
$my_excerpt = get_the_excerpt();
if ( $my_excerpt != '' ) {
    // Some string manipulation performed
}
echo $my_excerpt; // Outputs the processed value to the page
```

Or if you have an ID, get the post then sue the post_excerpt member var

e.g.

```
$post = get_post( $post_id );
echo $post->post_excerpt;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code and just change your `page_id`:

```
<?php $my_query = new WP_Query('page_id=20');
while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post();
$do_not_duplicate = $post->ID;?>
 <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
    <div class="text">

        <?php echo wp_trim_words( get_the_content(), 15, '...' ); ?>
 <a href="<?php echo get_page_link(); ?>" class="read-more">Read More</a>
    </div>

 <?php endwhile; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

For one liner addicts like me. Change 69 by your page ID.

```
<?= apply_filters('the_content', get_post(69)->post_content); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can do this with a shortcode. add the following to function.php

```
function lorem_func($attr) {
$txt = "<p>Lorem ipsum dolor .........</p>";
shortcode_atts(
 array(
    'repeat' => 1,
 ), $attr
);
return str_repeat($txt, $attr['repeat'] );
}
add_shortcode('lorem', 'lorem_func');
```

To render within content use;

```
[lorem repeat="2"]
```

Just need to mod the "Lorem ipsum dolor ........." for the length required. And the lorum repeat=2 change to the required amount of paragraphs. In the above example =2 means 2 paragraphs, so its multifuctional.

Answer (score 0):

Already answered but i think a much more handier function is get_post_field( 'fieldname', $post_id );

So in your case:

```
echo get_post_field( 'post_excerpt', $post_id );
```