# One information repeated on multiple locations on one site

Tags: database

I have a website with lots of information that are repeated multiple locations on my site. I'd like to link each bit of information in one cell in one database. If I'd like to change information, I need to do it in one place and all the others will be updated as well. How to achieve that?

-SidSid Keränen, muuta.net

Comment: I have detailed comic stories in multiple locations on my site. One documents all possible info, the others only part. If I am talking about certain story (for example in different foreign prints), I'd like to repeat part of that info there. Is if possible to make a list of info to refer to? If I have to change info, I need to fix it in one "list". For example I have a story location linked in multiple pages. Is it possible to have that link info in one place? If I have to change it, it will be changed throughout the entire site? No coding if possible. No php experience. Database ok. Plugin?

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to achieve this.

1. You can use a widget and [custom widgetareas](https://codex.wordpress.org/Widgetizing_Themes#How_to_Register_a_Widget_Area) or print it with a plugin like [widget on pages](https://wordpress.org/plugins/widgets-on-pages/).
2. You can create a page and print the pages content [like this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/101823/get-the-content-of-a-specific-page-by-id). (you can 301 redirect that page to the homepage to disallow users to hit the page directly)
3. You can use an [option framework](http://wpcrux.com/blog/wordpress-options-frameworks/) and define the content
   there.
4. If you have multiple different infos to display, you could create
   a [custom post type](https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types#Custom_Post_Types).

Comment: I have made repeating submenus with javascript. Should I ultimately do the same with every single repeating links and other junks of information? I am not sure if javascript is the best solution since I've got hundreds of pages and thousands of links and other junks of information. And I was hoping to have more decent table for it with plugin or such. Script of javascript is not necessarily the easiest way to handle big amount of data. I thought if somebody else's got similar task to achieve with Wordpress.